# Apply Pattern to a 3d image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to apply a pattern to a 3d image using javascript.I have a sample image like this
[image]

and a pattern like this

[image]

I want to apply pattern like this to that shirt for this I use canvas put first image as background image of canvas and apply pattern by using this code of javascript

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<titleLab></title>

<style>
#mycanvas{
border:1px solid #000000;
background-image:url('image/shirt.jpeg');
 background-size:cover
}
</style>
<script>
function drawShape(){
  // get the canvas element using the DOM
  var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

  // Make sure we don't execute when canvas isn't supported
  if (canvas.getContext){


    // use getContext to use the canvas for drawing
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // create new image object to use as pattern
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'pattern.jpg';
    img.onload = function(){
       // create pattern
       var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(img,'repeat');
       ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;1
       ctx.fillRect(10,100,100,100);
    }

  } else {
    alert('You need Safari or Firefox 1.5+ to see this demo.');
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="drawShape();">
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="249" height="428">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I identify paths to fill the shirt . When it fills it looks like a sticker put on it , How to make it realistic.Is there any library available so that I learn from there.Need help.
Thanks.

Comment: How about this: You use photoshop, crop the shirt, save as a TRANSPARENT 24BIT PNG file. Then you load the image and set a `background-image` with your pattern. BAMM!!! You got yourself SUPER BROWSER COMPATIBILITY and NO JAVASCRIPT AT ALL!

Comment: Btw, why is this with the tags `jquery` and `design-patterns`?

Comment: This is an often requested capability, but...No, there is no worthwhile method using html canvas to automatically apply a complex texture to a 2D image.  The solution is to use Photoshop to create a `displacement map` that can apply your checkered texture to your 2D shirt: http://designshack.net/articles/software/apply-graphics-to-textured-surfaces-with-displacement-maps/  **Do use Photoshop--NOT html canvas**

Answer (score 3):

have a loog on the link below

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/kzfKD/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img1 = new Image();
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {

    img1.onload = function () {
        start();
    }
    img1.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/4jiSz1.png";
}
img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/BooMu1.png";

function start() {

    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";

    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.globalAlpha = .10;
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

}


<canvas id="canvas" width=436 height=567></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi, what is that shirt image file in your fiddle? How can I generate other parts for a shirt, like the hands or cuffs so it has those shadows?